# Alamofire to monitor network status

Tags: ios, alamofire, swift2

About **Alamofire** -- **NetworkReachabilityManager** listening network status, I have the following two questions.

1.I need to start listening to the network status in which method?

2.If I want to network status monitoring in ***- application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:*** method, whether to need to delay?

I hope you can help me?

Answer (score 1):

There is a custom class called Reachability (https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability)
It works with Grand Central Dispatch so it handles the notifications when connectivity is reached or lost, the author warns you about changing it's name because some apps have been reported as denied during the App Store review process because the SDK has already defined a class with the same name